# how to compare the key in the array of object and modify it using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I have two objects obj1 and obj2, how to loop through array key `children` and if code name matches, then add the name key in the object obj2, get the object.

How to loop through object of objects and match the key and push the key to get the new object in javascript

```js
function newObject(obj1, obj2) {
  var result = obj1.map(e => {
    if ('children' in e)
      e.children = e.children.map(child => {
        if ('children' in child)
          child.children = child.children.map(c => {
            name: c.name
          });
        return child;
      });
    return e;
  })
  return result
}

var obj1 = [{
  "id": 1,
  "item": "node1",
  "children": [{
      "id": 2,
      "code": "countries",
      "title": "Country",
      "children": [{
          "cid": 12,
          "code": "S1",
          "name": "SG",
          "children": [{
            "id": 4,
            "code": "C1",
            "name": "City"
          }]
        },
        {
          "cid": 13,
          "code": "S2",
          "name": "TH"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "code": "Groceries",
      "title": "Grocery",
      "children": [{
          "cid": 11,
          "code": "G1",
          "name": "Fruits"
        },
        {
          "cid": 10,
          "code": "G2",
          "name": "Vegetables"
        }
      ]
    }, {
      "id": 3,
      "code": "lists",
      "title": "Option"
    }
  ]
}];

var obj2 = [{
    id: 1,
    code: "G1",
    status: "active"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    code: "S2",
    status: "inactive"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    code: "C1",
    status: "active"
  }
];

console.log(this.newObject(obj1, obj2));
```

Expected Output

```
[
  {id:1, name: "Fruits",code:"G1", status:"active"},
  {id:2, name: "TH",code:"S2", status:"inactive"},
  {id:3, name: "city",code:"C1", status:"active"}
]
```

Comment: I made you a snippet and fixed your object.

Comment: @mplungjan thanks for reply, but my expected output is different,

Comment: I did not fix your PROBLEM, only fixed your INVALID OBJECT

Comment: check  [my stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-xiksqr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check this [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-xiksqr)
I fixed your object and you can find your expectation in the console

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged. A good answer stands on it's own and is not *just* code, it also explains how it fixed the problem.

Comment: Discouraged @jon-p !!  I think he needs help and not a story to say nothing :)